# create_function() using option-tree plugin depreciated

Tags: wordpress

I have installed a wordpress theme I bought online. Then followed by option-tree plugin installation which is part of the requirements of the template.

I get an error

> Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/trans/webapps/ochokitours_com_wp_app/wp-content/plugins/option-tree/includes/ot-functions-admin.php on line 69

everytime the page is loading. This is the line:

```
  add_filter( 'option_page_capability_' . ot_options_id(), create_function( '$caps', "return '$caps';" ), 999 );
```

I expect the template to run smoothly with the plugin, but the error keeps popping up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the typical function() creation instead of a deprecated create_function() to create functions.

```
 add_filter( 'option_page_capability_' . ot_options_id(), create_function( '$caps', "return '$caps';" ), 999 );
```

Replace with below code:

```
 add_filter( 'option_page_capability_' . ot_options_id(), function($caps) {return $caps;},999);
```

If you wanted to replace more create_function() to anonymous functions, You can try [Rector](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector).

Answer (score 0):

This is a notice and it's shown because the plugin you're using is [create_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) which is DEPRECATED after php 7, so you have 2 workarounds:

- use another plugin or ask plugin developers to update their plugin
- Just ignore this and add the below codes to your themes's `functions.php` to disable showing notices

  `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
  ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );`